# Java - How to subclass the generic ArrayList so that instances of MyArrayList<foo> will be subclasses of ArrayList<foo>?

Tags: java, generics, arraylist

I want to keep my subclass generic, and all I want to change is the `add(Object)` method of ArrayList so that it won't add anything when you call `arrayList.add(null)` (the normal implementation of ArrayList will add the `null`; I want it to do nothing).

Comment: The thought police are swarming all over this one. The OP's requirement is clearly stated, and I don't see any reason why the question couldn't be answered as asked. @fbafelip has shown how to do it. The delegation alternatives mentioned require orders of magnitude more code.

Comment: There are many ways to add elements to an `ArrayList<T>` (or any `List<T>`): `add( T )`, `add( int, T )`, `addAll( Collection<T> )`, `addAll( int, Collection<T> )`, through the constructors, and through the `add` methods of `Iterator<T>` and `ListIterator<T>`, and through modifying a view returned with `subList` in any of the above ways. Do you need to handle all of these?

Comment: The thought police?  Really, you're going to compare my answer to the totalitarian state?  Because all I'm using is an argument from authority... right gotcha.

Comment: @AmirAfghani - Ha, I think he meant your answer had an element of mind-reading, not that it was orwellian in nature \*stays neutral\*

Comment: @EJP FWIW, I think implementing `List` with composition and extending `ArrayList` directly are about equal amounts of work in this case, if the goal is indeed to make a `null`-less `ArrayList` that supports all the operations. If I were in the OP's position I would seriously consider avoiding implementing this data structure at all.

Comment: @trutheality Implementing `List` in its entirety is more work than overriding a subset of its methods.

Comment: @EJP I don't consider "implementing" one-liners like `E remove(E item){return myList.remove(E);}` to be considerable work. It's literally less than 60 lines of dummy code, about 40 of which any decent IDE will automatically fill in for you.

Comment: @truthreality It is still measurable non-zero work, and being new code it has to be tested too.

Comment: This particular design decision seems to go against the Liskov substitution principle... is there a better way for you to achieve this? E.g. create a new method instead of overriding super's method(s).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You really should favor composition over inheritance in this case, because if you forget to override one of the methods from ArrayList which add/change an element (you could forget to override set, for example), it will still be possible to have null elements.

But since the question was about how to subclass ArrayList, here is how you do it:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MyArrayList<T> extends ArrayList<T> {
    public boolean add(T element) {
        if (element != null) return super.add(element);
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: This solution is reasonable if you can guarantee that this is the only place where you will modify the behavior of the array list, because then this implementation detail is transparent externally.

Comment: Why didn't you like my edited version? It was identical in behaviour but was better code (for several reasons).

Comment: @Bohemian I just wanted to keep it more explicit, since it is a sample code.

Answer (score 10):

This is an example where you should favor composition over inheritance.

Instead of extending `ArrayList`, you should create a class that has an `ArrayList` member field and exposes an `add` method that does the right thing.

Read [Effective Java](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/effective/). Here is the [example](http://books.google.com/books?id=ka2VUBqHiWkC&lpg=PA67&dq=Classes%20and%20Interfaces%20effective%20java&pg=PA81#v=onepage&q=Classes%20and%20Interfaces%20effective%20java&f=false) that describes this issue specifically.

Comment: I agree that he should favor composition over inheritance, but maybe he will pass the ArrayList to an external library, so composition won't work in that case. He ask about how to subclass it, not if he should.

Comment: Your citation and example do not apply. The OP *specifically wants* whatever the behaviour of the superclass is.

Comment: This really does not help the questioner. His next question would be:  > How to subclass the generic List so that instances of MyList<foo> will be subclasses of List<foo>?

Comment: @EJP It seems to me that Amir's citations *do* apply.  Yes, the OP's objective *is* clearly stated. And yes, Amir doesn't answer the question asked.  However, he raises a good point that the OP may not have thought of.  Though not directly stated, it certainly *looks* like the OP's end objective is to not have `null` values in his `List`.  The direct answer to his question may or may not give him that behavior, depending on the implementation of `ArrayList`.  There is nothing wrong with providing an answer that illuminates possible underlying issues rather than giving a direct answer.

Comment: @EJP Please explain how the example does not apply.  I'm open to hearing how you cannot achieve what the OP is asking for using the method I described

Comment: @fbafelipe The OP did not describe his use case, but lets say you're right and he wanted to pass the ArrayList to an extenal library.  Why is this approach prohibitive?  You could simply expose a getter on the list itself.

Comment: @AmirAfghani (1) The example you linked to says that if you use inheritance, 'a subclass relies on the implementation details of its superclass'. That is exactly what the OP wants. (2) You are putting words into my mouth. I have not said anywhere that you cannot achieve it via composition. Indeed I said in another comment that doing so requires orders of magnitude more code, which implies the opposite of what you are ascribing to me.

Comment: @TimPote No underlying issues have been illuminated here. The underlying issue is that the OP has to implement all the `addXXX()` methods, and consider `subList()` as well. That's not stated anywhere here.

Comment: @AmirAfghani "The OP did not describe his use case" Thats exacly why you should not make an assumption like you did, when there are cases where it may be a good idea to subclass ArrayList (if it were always a bad idea, they would make it a final class). "but lets say you're right and he wanted to pass the ArrayList to an extenal library. Why is this approach prohibitive?" How would you pass MyArrayList to, say, "public void addStuff(ArrayList<Foo> l)" if MyArrayList is not a subclass of ArrayList?

Comment: The class that encapsulates the ArrayList member would expose it in a getter.

Comment: @AmirAfghani But that would allow addStuff() method to add null elements.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered implementing a filter where the add method would be called? If it is being called from only one place in your code, then that might be easiest. A simple if statement might work.

```
if (input/object != null) { 
    arrayList.add(input/object);
} 
else { 
    //do something else instead, or nothing
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's perfectly respectable to want to restrict what goes into a List, though silently disregarding an argument is questionable. Still, this is why we have [Apache Commons Collections](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/javadocs/api-release/index.html). There's probably a Guava equivalent. Use one of them to declare a `final` subclass of `ArrayList`, so no one can subvert your intentions.